# How to post in EXTJS Forums ,To know abt Logging and Exception handling is available !

Tags: c#, asp.net, extjs

I need to know, whether extjs 3.1 is available of exception handling and logging build in library .

Like Logging the exception as log file , with the specification of error whether it is major or minor or critical or info.
new log file creating on specified size exceeded. etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing like that built in.  AFAIK, this is not something you'll find in many (any?) JS-based frameworks.  Exception handling and logging take a lot of code to do framework-wide (not to mention the added performance overhead), so you'd never want to build that in without some way of extracting it back out for a production build.  While possible in theory, this would basically involve writing or extending an existing JS parser that could do so, which would be no small feat.

Re: exception handling, there is some in the framework where it makes sense, but really in any development framework, runtime errors usually bubble up by design.  There is often not a good default way to handle an exception (as opposed to an end application which can choose to display the error to the user in some meaningful way).  More importantly, since the end user of a framework is you, the developer, you'll want to know immediately about any runtime exceptions in your code (or even in the framework itself for that matter).

Logging is definitely possible (and useful) but you'll have to roll your own as needed.

Answer (score 1):

To post in the [ExtJS forums](http://www.extjs.com/forum/), you'll first need to [create a user profile](http://www.extjs.com/forum/register.php). Then you'll be able to create new topics and post answers to other topics.

I haven't explored the area of exception handling and logging in ExtJS. If **bmoeskau** visits this question, he might be able to tell you.

By the way, ExtJS is now available in version 3.2 :)

Comment: +1 for taking the time to explain how to sign up on a forum (and for name-dropping ;)

Comment: @bmoeskau: I monitor the ExtJS tag, and I can tell from your responses that you definitely know a lot about ExtJS - and I respect that :)